# Is it possible to make swipe refresh layout spinner have a static position relative to RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

Currently when I call `SwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true)` a spinner will appear. However, when I scroll the underlying `RecyclerView` upon which `SwipeRefreshLayout` wraps around, the spinner stays in the same place. (e.i. its position is relative to the `SwipeRefreshLayout`).

How would I go about changing it so that the spinners position is relative to the `RecyclerView`. In other words, when I do `SwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true)` and scroll down. The spinner is no longer visible. And when I scroll back up, it is visible.